# how to write crash script to dump kernel variable in rbtree

Tags: crash

Would like dump the hrtimer infor in hrtimer_cpu_base.
But there are lots of timer in system with rbtree.
Is there any script/method could help dump all hrtimers?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Using tree command in crash

```
crash> hrtimer_cpu_base.clock_base[0].active.rb_root.rb_root  ffff912c6fc1d040
  clock_base[0].active.rb_root.rb_root = {
    rb_node = 0xffffb07590be7e90
  },

crash> tree -o hrtimer.node -N 0xffffb07590be7e90 -s hrtimer.function
ffffb07590be7e90
  function = 0xffffffffa537d0b0
ffffb07590ddbe90
  function = 0xffffffffa537d0b0
ffffb07584faba58
  function = 0xffffffffa537d0b0
ffff912c6fc1d680
  function = 0xffffffffa538da30
ffffb07586847e88
  function = 0xffffffffa537d0b0
ffff912c6fc1d860
  function = 0xffffffffa53d40d0
ffffb07586bffe88
  function = 0xffffffffa537d0b0
ffffb07584df7e88
  function = 0xffffffffa537d0b0
```

Comment: timer -r, could also dump the hrtimer